# Почему GetForegroundWindow сразу меняет значение?

Tags: c#, winapi

Проблема заключается в том, что активное окно не меняется, а pointer GetForegroundWindow меняет значение. 
Т.е в моем случае при клике на блокнот, форма исчезает и в ту же секунду появляется.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
void FindF2B(){
var hWndParent = FindWindow("Notepad", "Untitled - Notepad");
if(GetForegroundWindow() == hWndParent){
    if(this.InvokeRequired){
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate{ this.Hide();}));
    }
        }else{
    if(this.InvokeRequired){
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate{ this.Show();}));
        }
}
```

Comment: Вы неправильно делаете Show. Делая Show *ForegroundWindow* становится ваше окно. Почитайте внимательно функцию *SetWindowPos* (с флагами SWP_NOACTIVATE SWP_NOZORDER SWP_SHOWWINDOW) должно помочь

Comment: Ещё, ваше окно покажется, а если его активируют - оно спрячется (согласно вашему правилу). Кроме hWndParent вам всётаки в "фильтр" нужно ещё и ваше окно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    void FindF2B(){
     var hWndParent = FindWindow("Notepad", "Untitled - Notepad");
     var myFormWindow = FindWindow(null, "Location");
      if(GetForegroundWindow() == hWndParent && GetForegroundWindow() != IntPtr.Zero){
       ShowWindow(myFormWindow , 1);
    }else{
       ShowWindow(myFormWindow , 0);
 }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
```